# Looking to disable a set of fields unless a radio button is marked

Tags: javascript, jquery, conditional-statements, hidden

I have uploaded the HTML / CSS / JS at: http://jsfiddle.net/mbender/aH8Ax/

I know the problem probably lies within the JS, as i have almost no experience with it.

```
$(function () {
    var $promised = $("input[name='RadioGroup1']");
    $promised.each(function () {
        $(this).on("click", function () {
            $promised.each(function () {
                var textField = $(this).nextAll("input").first();
                if (textField) textField.prop("disabled", !this.checked);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

There is also a conditionally hidden element to work around.  You will see what i mean in the fiddle

Comment: i am looking to only be able to edit the "USA Address Fields" when the USA radio button is marked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input field is disabled whenever the attribute 'disabled' is present in the tag, it doesn't matter what the value is set to. What you can do is loop through all the input elements inside of the USA section and call

```
.removeAttribute('disabled');
```

if the user selects the USA radio button.

EDIT: something like this should work (as long as you have JQuery)

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type=text/javascript>
$(function() {
  var $promised = $("input[name='RadioGroup1']");
  $promised.each(function() {
    $(this).on("click",function() {

      var USARadio = document.getElementById("RadioGroup1_0");
      if(USARadio.checked == true){
        toggleUSA(true);
      }
        else{
          toggleUSA(false);
        }
    });    
  });
});   
function toggleUSA(disable){
  var USATable = document.getElementById("rowThree");
  var USAInputs = USATable.getElementsByTagName("input");
  for(var i=0;i<USAInputs.length;i++){
    if(disable == true)
      USAInputs[i].removeAttribute("disabled");
    else
      USAInputs[i].setAttribute("disabled", "true");
  }
}    
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response! can you give me an idea of how to do that exactly? Sorry im a noob when it comes to JS, I've only managed to get it functioning to this level with the help of this site and JSFiddle

Comment: Edited my original post

Comment: I updated the post to contain the script you need to reference JQuery